# When USB drive is connected, message on console using udev

Tags: linux, usb, udev

Is it possible to send some message like Device Added or Removed etc to console on my target using udev rules?

Comment: Please see http://reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html

Comment: Link says "udev does not run these programs on any active terminal, and it does not execute them under the context of a shell. Be sure to ensure your program is marked executable, if it is a shell script ensure it starts with an appropriate shebang (e.g. #!/bin/sh), and do not expect any standard output to appear on your terminal." 


Please let me know if that means there is no other way to print on console ? or is there a way to output to console